# How to connect to a remote files server in Netbeans using SFTP?

Tags: java, php, netbeans, remote-server

I'm currently building a mobile application and want to be able to access some PHP files that I have stored on a server. I'm building the application in Netbeans and ran into the following error when trying to establish an SFTP connection;

**(Cause :java.net.ConnectionException: Connection Refused)**

The connection works fine if I use FTP (which is less secure?) to establish the connection, but not with SFTP.

I provide the following input (example):

[Netbeans screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4u6R.png)

Can anyone pinpoint what the problem is and how to correct it? Thanks.

Comment: "connection refused" is that remote system set up for sftp?

Comment: SFTP is FTP over SSH. Having a FTP server doesn't mean you have SFTP too. You need to have an active SSH server on the remote machine in order to use SFTP.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not sure if it does. How would I set that up?

Comment: @BackSlash Okay, so I would need to buy an extra server to support SSH? Is FTP not secure enough to persist with?

Comment: @Skin99 No additional servers needed, SSH (like FTP) is software, not hardware. You just need to install and configure the SSH package in your server. It *should* be more secure than plain FTP, as it's FTP over a secure channel (SSH)

Comment: @BackSlash Thank you. I will give that a try.